# Reading the configuration via GCP Secret Manager does not work when running config-server image as a Cloud Run Service

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-secret-manager

I am running [hyness/spring-cloud-config-server](https://hub.docker.com/r/hyness/spring-cloud-config-server/) as a docker image as below, and it works fine.

```
docker run -it -p 8888:8888 \
    -v /etc/springboot_configs/application.yaml:/config/application.yaml \
      hyness/spring-cloud-config-server:3.0.5
```

Invoking the below command works and it fetches the values from the git as expected.

`curl http://localhost:8888/spboot-sink/gcpnpr`

Now, I am trying to run this container to run as a cloud run service, and the application.yaml is provided as a secret and expected to work as a volume in the cloud run.

Here is how, I am running the cloud run command:

```
gcloud run deploy spring-cloud-config-server \
--image=us-west1-docker.pkg.dev/gcp-demo-prj/testrepo/spring-cloud-config-server@sha256:xxxxxxx \
--vpc-connector=projects/gcp-demo-prj/locations/us-west1/connectors/serverless-connector \
--allow-unauthenticated \
--port=8888 \
--service-account=xxxx-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com \
--memory=1Gi \
--min-instances=1 \
--max-instances=2 \
--set-secrets=/config/application.yaml=configserver:latest \
--region=us-west1 \
--project=gcp-demo-prj
```

However it does not work. The service is running fine, but I am not able to fetch the details from the git.

I tried to follow this [article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/mount-a-file-as-a-volume-in-cloud-run-facc74c02cc6) and GCP official document on how to mount volumes as [secret](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/secrets#mounting-secrets-service) in cloud run, however I was not successful.

Here is a snippet of error log:

```
Could not open file at path /config/application-default.yml. The path is in a mounted secrets volume, but the exact path does not correspond to any secret specified in the mount configuration.
```

Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Are you sure about the secret name? No typo?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere, here is the secret ID:  `projects/xxxxxx/secrets/configserver`.

Comment: Is the secret in that project: gcp-demo-prj ?

Comment: Yes. This is the only project, I am having now.

Comment: I have no clues, except a secret missing or not reachable.

Comment: can you refer to this link : [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65824065/15774176)  is it helpful?