# Weird warning in gcloud console: The path is in a mounted secrets volume [...] but does not correspond to any secret

Tags: google-cloud-functions, gcloud, google-secret-manager

I'm deploying a gcloud function with two mounted secrets (from google secret manager), my local dir structure is the following:

```
├── index.js
├── mounted-secret-config
│   ├── config.js
├── mounted-secret-credentials
│   └── googleServiceAccountCredentials.json
├── package-lock.json
└── package.json
```

`config.js` and `googleServiceAccountCredentials.json` are ignored so the deploy process doesn't upload them.

I deploy using this command:

```
gcloud functions deploy <...> --region <...> --trigger-http --runtime nodejs16 --allow-unauthenticated --gen2 --memory 256Mi --set-secrets=/workspace/mounted-secret-config/config.js=configjs:latest,/workspace/mounted-secret-credentials/googleServiceAccountCredentials.json=googleServiceAccountCredentials:latest
```

It works, the node app finds the files and overall works but after each deploy I see this in the gcloud logs:

```
2022-08-26 10:11:18.130 CEST Could not open file at path /secret_volume_0/config. The path is in a mounted secrets volume, but the exact path does not correspond to any secret specified in the mount configuration.
Warning
2022-08-26 10:11:18.182 CEST Could not open file at path /secret_volume_0/package.json. The path is in a mounted secrets volume, but the exact path does not correspond to any secret specified in the mount configuration.
Warning
```

And after each http request to my service i get:

```
2022-08-26 10:05:33.511 CEST Could not open file at path /workspace/mounted-secret-config/config. The path is in a mounted secrets volume, but the exact path does not correspond to any secret specified in the mount configuration.
Warning
2022-08-26 10:05:33.572 CEST Could not open file at path /workspace/mounted-secret-config/package.json. The path is in a mounted secrets volume, but the exact path does not correspond to any secret specified in the mount configuration.
```

I've no idea what's going on here, I don't even know who's logging this. `/workspace/mounted-secret-config/config` doesn't exist, but `/workspace/mounted-secret-config/config.js` (note the .js extension) does, and the app finds it or it would not even start. `/workspace/mounted-secret-config/package.json` this doesn't but it isn't supposed to, who's even trying to access it? And why it doesn't complain about the other mounted secret?

config.js is required with: `require('./mounted-secret-config/config')`

If I change it to `require('./mounted-secret-config/config.js')` (adding .js) one of the two warnings disappears. Is node trying to import the exact name (giving the warning) and then falling back to `config.js`? But what about the `package.json`?

Comment: Have you referred to this [Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65817334/kubernetes-deployment-mounts-secret-as-a-folder-instead-of-a-file/65824065#65824065)

Comment: @SandeepVokkareni I don't think any of that applies to my case

Comment: Can you try with the command '--update-secrets' instead of '--set-secrets' and meanwhile can you share the entire log error message to further debug the issue. Can you confirm to us that your runtime service account has a Secret Manager Secret Accessor role or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a real solution, more like a workaround, feel free to add a real solution if you find it.

What I did to "fix" the problem was change the format of my config file from `.js` to `.json` (easy in my case because it only contained a dictionary with few keys/values)

Everything else stayed the same, I still read the file with `require`. I don't know what weird thing node was doing with the `.js`, but it doesn't do it with `.json`.

Both warning disappeared (including the one about `package.json`).